# GAE - app.yaml for static page AND Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, static, app.yaml

I am trying to create a static html component (that will be usable offline) for a Google App that is otherwise Python.

I can't seem to get the `app.yaml` file configured correctly for that.

```
handlers:

  # Serve images and JSON as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg|json|ico))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg|json|ico)$
  application_readable: true

- url: \/(static)\/(index)\.html
  static_files: static/\1/index.html
  upload: static\/index.html

- url: /
  script: roomusage.app
  login: required
  secure: always

- url: /welcome
  script: roomusage.app
  login: required
  secure: always

- url: /record
  script: record_usage.app
  login: required
  secure: always
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
appcfg.py: error: Error parsing C:\gcloud\dev-myapp\app.yaml: Unable to assign value '\/(static)\/(index)\.html' to attribute 'url':
Value '\/(static)\/(index)\.html' for url does not match expression '^(?:(?!\^)/.*|\..*|(\(.).*(?!\$).)$'
  in "C:\gcloud\dev-myapp\app.yaml", line 25, column 8.
2017-12-08 09:27:50 (Process exited with code 2)
```

Comment: The `\/(static)\/(index)\.html` pattern is the likely suspect. What URLs are you trying to match with it and what parameters do you want to identify in them?

Comment: URL I'm trying to match it with: `/static/index.html` (don't understand the second part of the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\/(static)\/(index)\.html` pattern is an invalid URL regex pattern.

First - the pattern can't start with `\` - you don't need to escape `/`.

The round paranthesis in the pattern are used to identify positional groupings which can then be referred to as parameters by `\1`, `\2`, etc in subsequent statements, like  `static_files`, for example. From the `url` row in the [Handlers elements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) table:

> **url**
>
> Required element under **handlers**. The URL pattern, as a regular
>   expression. The expression can contain groupings that can be referred
>   to in the file path to the script with regular expression
>   back-references. For example, **/profile/(.*)/(.*)** would match the
>   URL **/profile/edit/manager** and use **edit** and **manager** as the
>   first and second groupings.

If you don't need such grouping/parameters then don't use the round paranthesis in your patterns. So to match just `/static/index.html` you could have:

```
- url: /static/index\.html
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
```

But you should note that the above is redundant if you also have:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```